# Json десериализация

Tags: java, json, jackson

При попытке десериализовать JSON примерно такого вида

```json
{"id":0,"name":"alexkekiy",
"coordinates":{"x":5,"y":6.6},"creationDate":"22-02-2024 07:24",
"health":4,"loyal":true,"height":5.5,"weaponType":"BOLT_PISTOL",
"chapter":{"name":"55","parentLegion":"","world":"ew"}
}
```

На выходе получается `LinkedHashMap` вместо нормального POJO, вследствие чего вылетает `ClassCastException`

Десериализую библиотекой Jackson следующим способом:

```java
public static <T> ArrayList<T> readAndUpdate(String fileName) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"));
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    ArrayList<T> data = new ArrayList<>();
    try (FileReader fis = new FileReader(fileName);
         BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fis)) {
        String line;
        while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
            data.add(mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<T>() {}).readValue(line));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Метод вызывается в мейне

```
public static final PriorityQueue<SpaceMarine> collection = new PriorityQueue<>();    
collection.addAll(readAndUpdate(fileName));
```

Теперь, собственно, занавес - если указать в `typeReference` не `T`, а `SpaceMarine`, все работает, но я хочу сохранить абстрактность конвертирующего метода.
Очевидно проблема в этом, но как ее решить, не понимаю

Comment: Можно объект TypeReference через параметры readAndUpdate передать, потом в readerFor его же передать вместо создания нового. Снаружи TypeRefernce с конкретным типом создаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы сохранить абстрактность можно использовать TypeReference в качестве параметра, чтобы передать информацию о типе:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> readAndUpdate(String fileName, TypeReference<T> typeReference) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"));
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

    ArrayList<T> data = new ArrayList<>();
    try (FileReader fis = new FileReader(fileName);
         BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fis)) {
         String line;
         while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
            data.add(mapper.readValue(line, typeReference));
         }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Да,пожалуй это было очевидно,спасибо